# Why is Pigeonhole sort not ideal for key count smaller than element count?

Tags: complexity-theory, sorting

Wikipedia has this about Pigeonhole sort:

> Pigeonhole sorting is a sorting algorithm that is suitable for sorting lists of elements where the number of elements (n) and the length of the range of possible key values (N) are approximately the same.

I can see how it would be counterproductive to have more key values than elements, since we must iterate through all key values at the end of the algorithm.  But I don't get why it would be a problem to have far fewer keys than elements.

I'd appreciate help understanding this.

Comment: It's not much a problem to have fewer.